# Ethereum on AWS

Tags: go-ethereum, aws

I am building environment on AWS where I would like for my ethereum node not to be publicly accessible.
The server with ethereum is in private subnet which has internet connection over nat gateway.

Is there a suggestion how can I setup this env?

geth can talk to peers but I think peers cant talk back since there is no way back.

The server doesn't have public IP and is totally private.

Is it possible maybe to route geth p2p port, i think is 30303 or it needs public ip to talk to peers.

Thanks !